# How to display image from database instead of image path using jQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I want to display image from my database which stores the path to the image's location. Following code gives me the image path only in the output. What changes do I need to make in order for image to appear instead of image path?

```
GetBusinessCategoryList: function () {
            debugger;               
            var data = JSON2.stringify({                        
                });
            $.ajax(
                {
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:44719/Modules/BusinessCategoryView/Service/BusinessCategoryWebService.asmx/GetAllBusinessCategory',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("ok");
                        var returnedData = result;
                        BusinessManagement.BindBusinessCategoryList(returnedData);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });            
        },
        BindBusinessCategoryList: function (data) {
            debugger;
            var cLst = data.d;                
            if (cLst.length > 0) {                    
                headElements += '<table id="customerTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >';
                headElements += '<thead class="sfHeadingone">';
                headElements += '<tr><th align="left">Category Image</th>';
                ;
                headElements += '</thead>';
                $('#tblGrid').html(headElements);
                var i = 0;
                if (i === 0) {
                    bodyElements += '<tbody>';
                }
                $.each(cLst, function (index, value) {

                        bodyElements += "<td>" + value.CategoryImage + "</td>";                    
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**img**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) to display an image. Pass the image url to the `src` attribute of the img tag

```
bodyElements += "<td><img src='" + value.CategoryImage + "'></td>";
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This partially solved my problem as the console still says "Failed to load resource" but I should be able to figure that one out